# Adding Additional Build Directories in Build-Time in CMake (and Forcing a Reconfiguration of the Target)

Tags: python, c++, cmake

Currently I have a CMake project where arbitrary source files can be generated and added to a target during build-time with a pyhton script. Inclusion of the generated source files force a reconfiguration of the target with the use of add_custom_command and generating a CMake file that includes the list of source files and providing this file as a dependency.

I need to extend this by allowing this python script to generate include directories. I tried to extend this feature, but I could not make the changes in include directories and the CMake file to force a reconfiguration.

Now I want to explain the implementation in detail:

We first add the custom command:

```
        add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Generated.timestamp
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env PYTHONPATH=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/python ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ${generatorFile} ${ARG_GENERATOR_ARGUMENTS}
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Generated.timestamp
                DEPENDS ${generatorFile}
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
                COMMENT "Generate source code from ${generatorFile}"
        )
```

The custom command is calling the python script `${generatorFile}` with the respective arguments `${ARG_GENERATOR_ARGUMENTS}`. We generate a timestamp file to detect changes
`${generatorFile}`.

The python script `${generatorFile}` will write to a file called `Generated.cmake`.
So we create it with:

```
        execute_process(
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Generated.cmake
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        )
```

We also add it as a dependency to our target `${ARG_NAME}`.

```
        target_sources(${ARG_NAME} PRIVATE 
            ${nonGeneratedFiles}
            ${generatedFiles}   
            ${ARG_FILES} 
            ${cppFiles}
            ${generatorFile}
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Generated.cmake
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Generated.timestamp)
```

The generated cmake file `Generated.cmake` has the following format:

```
set(generatedFiles ...)
set(nonGeneratedFiles ...)
set(generatedIncludeDirs ...)
set_source_files_properties(${generatedFiles} PROPERTIES GENERATED 1)
```

It sets 3 variables that are used by the target as their sources as well as include directories. The additional directories I set with:

```
        target_include_directories(${ARG_NAME} PRIVATE ${generatedIncludeDirs})
```

Now If I dont manually force configuration of the project with a second call to `cmake` or `make` the project fails in the first configuration with an error that says that the header is not in the include directories as it has not regarded the `${generatedIncludeDirs}` variable, but in the second call the project compiles fine.

I have tried multiple ways to fix this issue, here are what I tried and failed:

- Setting compile flags in the include CMake file where every included directory of `${generatedIncludeDirs}` becomes an additional flag of `-I${generatedIncludeDirs}`
  and setting it for the target.
- Using a second CMake file that is generated for the include directories. This means I had a second generated CMake file with a different name, that was also a source file for the target
- Setting the generated source files depend excplicitly on the generated cmake file with the CMake command

```
        set_source_files_properties(${generatedFiles} ${nonGeneratedFiles} PROPERTIES
            OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Generated.cmake
          )
```

- Setting `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` explicitly with the generated cmake file, tried with the following attempts:

  - `set_target_properties(${ARG_NAME} PROPERTIES CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Generated.cmake)`

and

- `set(CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Generated.cmake")`

As a workaround I tried to force a reconfiguration within the python script with:
(The string are read from python variables but they are equivalent to the following CMake variables used in this question)

```py
os.system("cmake --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}. --target ${ARG_NAME}")
```

Which triggers an infinite loop of configuring the target `${ARG_NAME}`. With the following command as the last line of the python script:

```py
os.system("cmake ../../../..")
```

Then the project compiles fine in the first call to `make`. I do not want to use this workaround if possible. How can I add include directories to a target during build time and force a reconfiguration of the target only when they are added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I could not find a solution to the above described problem, I have solved it by using the build script to generate a CMakeLists.txt file for the new sub-project and add it to the main CMake project as a subdirectory.